# Making and connecting hexagons on a rectangle grid

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I am creating a pathfinding application and I want to connect every hexgon(H) to its adjacent hexagons. The grid is a rectangle but it is populated with hexagons. The issue is the code right now to connect these hexagons is lengthy and extremely finicky. An example of what i am trying to achieve is:
[image]

The issue is that the connections between say one hexagon and its neighbours (range from 2-6 depending on their placement in the grid) is not working properly. An example of the code i am using right now to connect a hexagon with 6 neighbours is:

```
        currentState.graph().addEdge(i, i + 1, 1);
        currentState.graph().addEdge(i, i - HexBoard.rows + 1, 1);
        currentState.graph().addEdge(i, i - HexBoard.rows, 1);
        currentState.graph().addEdge(i, i + HexBoard.rows +1, 1);
        currentState.graph().addEdge(i, i + HexBoard.rows , 1);
```

The graph is essetialy the grid, addEdge adds a connection from src ->dest with cost(c) in order. Is there any algorithm or way to make my code less bulky ? (right now it is polluted with if-else clauses)?
The site which inspired me :https://clementmihailescu.github.io/Pathfinding-Visualizer/#

EDIT : The problem is not in drawing hexagons (They are already SVGs), it in assigning them edges and connections.

Comment: Perhaps you have not chosen proper coordinate system for easy walking. Look at [possible variants here](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/)

Comment: you should chose/describe your topology first (by numbering your hexagonal cells) and then use the numbering system to get neighbors instead of graph approach ... 2D hex grid is usually addressed with 2 numbers ... along 2 major axis ... so either +x and 30 deg slope or +30deg slope and -30 deg slope ...

Comment: @Spektre oh, as in use some number from (0,0 => x , y) and through that understand the edges and their approach?

Comment: yes as from the `i,j` index you can compute `x,y` position of your hexagon and also its all neighbors without any graphs/nodes/search ...  you can also reverse that so compute `i,j` from `x,y` ... you know for mouse selection etc ... You can also have stored all the hexagoninfo in 2D array indexed by `i,j` like terrain type, objects inside etc ...

Comment: I had some Answers in here about this however cant find them :( most likely got deleted over the years...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem...  To set a solid foundation, here's a hexagon grid class that is neither lengthy nor finicky, based on a simple data structure of a linear array.  A couple of notes...

- The `HexagonGrid` constructor accepts the hexagon grid dimensions in terms of the number of hexagons wide (`hexWidth`) by number of hexagons high (`hexHeight`).
- The `hexHeight` alternates by an additional hexagon every other column for a more pleasing appearance.  Thus an odd number for `hexWidth` bookends the hexagon grid with the same number of hexagons in the first and last columns.
- The `length` attribute represents the total number of hexagons in the grid.
- Each hexagon is referenced by a linear index from 0..`length`.
- The `hexagonIndex` method which takes (x,y) coordinates returns an the linear index based on an approximation of the closest hexagon.  Thus, when near the edges of a hexagon, the index returned might be a close neighbor.
- Am not totally satisfied with the class structure, but is sufficient to show the key algorithms involved in a linear indexed hexagon grid.

To aid in visualizing the linear indexing scheme, the code snippet displays the linear index value in the hexagon.  Such an indexing scheme offers the opportunity to have a parallel array of the same length which represents the characteristics of each specific hexagon by index.

Also exemplified is the ability to translate from mouse coordinates to the hexagon index, by clicking on any hexagon, which will redraw the hexagon with a thicker border.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

class HexagonGrid {

  constructor( hexWidth, hexHeight, edgeLength ) {
    this.hexWidth = hexWidth;
    this.hexHeight = hexHeight;
    this.edgeLength = edgeLength;
    
    this.cellWidthPair = this.hexHeight * 2 + 1;
    this.length = this.cellWidthPair * ( hexWidth / 2 |0 ) + hexHeight * ( hexWidth % 2 );
    
    this.dx = edgeLength * Math.sin( Math.PI / 6 );
    this.dy = edgeLength * Math.cos( Math.PI / 6 );
  }
  
  centerOfHexagon( i ) {
    let xPairNo = i % this.cellWidthPair;
    return {
      x: this.dx + this.edgeLength / 2 + ( i / this.cellWidthPair |0 ) * ( this.dx + this.edgeLength ) * 2 + ( this.hexHeight <= i % this.cellWidthPair ) * ( this.dx + this.edgeLength ),
      y: xPairNo < this.hexHeight ?  ( xPairNo + 1 ) * this.dy * 2 : this.dy + ( xPairNo - this.hexHeight ) * this.dy * 2
    };
  }
  
  hexagonIndex( point ) {
    let col = ( point.x - this.dx / 2 ) / ( this.dx + this.edgeLength ) |0;
    let row = ( point.y - ( col % 2 === 0 ) * this.dy ) / ( this.dy * 2 ) |0;
    let hexIndex = ( col / 2 |0 ) * this.cellWidthPair + ( col % 2 ) * this.hexHeight + row;
    //console.log( `(${point.x},${point.y}):  col=${col}  row=${row}  hexIndex=${hexIndex}` );
    return ( 0 <= hexIndex && hexIndex < this.length ? hexIndex : null );
  }
  
  edge( i ) {
    let topCheck = i % ( this.hexHeight + 0.5 );
    return (
      i < this.hexHeight
      || ( i + 1 ) % ( this.hexHeight + 0.5 ) === this.hexHeight
      || i % ( this.hexHeight + 0.5 ) === this.hexHeight
      || ( i + 1 ) % ( this.hexHeight + 0.5 ) === 0
      || i % ( this.hexHeight + 0.5 ) === 0
      || this.length - this.hexHeight < i
     );
  }
  
  drawHexagon( ctx, center, lineWidth ) {
    let halfEdge = this.edgeLength / 2;
    
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth || 1;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo( center.x - halfEdge, center.y - this.dy );
    ctx.lineTo( center.x + halfEdge, center.y - this.dy );
    ctx.lineTo( center.x + halfEdge + this.dx, center.y );
    ctx.lineTo( center.x + halfEdge, center.y + this.dy );
    ctx.lineTo( center.x - halfEdge, center.y + this.dy );
    ctx.lineTo( center.x - halfEdge - this.dx, center.y );
    ctx.lineTo( center.x - halfEdge, center.y - this.dy );
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  drawGrid( ctx, topLeft ) {
    ctx.font = '10px Arial';
    for ( let i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
      let center = this.centerOfHexagon( i );
      this.drawHexagon( ctx, { x: topLeft.x + center.x, y: topLeft.y + center.y } );

      ctx.fillStyle = this.edge( i ) ? 'red' : 'black';
      ctx.fillText( i, topLeft.x + center.x - 5, topLeft.y + center.y + 5 );
    }
  }
  
}

let myHexGrid = new HexagonGrid( 11, 5, 20 );
let gridLeftTop = { x: 20, y: 20 };
myHexGrid.drawGrid( ctx, gridLeftTop );

canvas.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function( event ) {
  let i = myHexGrid.hexagonIndex( { x: event.offsetX - gridLeftTop.x, y: event.offsetY - gridLeftTop.y } );
  if ( i !== null ) {
    let center = myHexGrid.centerOfHexagon( i );
    myHexGrid.drawHexagon( ctx, { x: gridLeftTop.x + center.x, y: gridLeftTop.y + center.y }, 3 );
  }
} );
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=1000 height=1000 />
```

A large benefit of the linear index is that it makes path searching easier, as each *interior* hexagon is surrounded by hexagons with relative indexes of -1, -6, -5, +1, +6, +5.  For example, applying the relative indexes to hexagon 18 results in a list of surrounding hexagons of 17, 12, 13, 19, 24, 23.

As a bonus, the `edge` method indicates whether the hexagon is on the edge of the grid.  (In the code snippet, the edge cells are identified by red text.)  Highly recommend that edge cells not be part of the pathing (ie, they are unreachable) as this simplifies any path searching.  Otherwise the pathing logic becomes very complex, as now if on an edge cell, the relative indexes indicating the surrounding hexagons no longer fully apply...

Comment: This actually makes sense however, my hexagons are already SVGs. So the portion of drawing them is more or less covered. However, the linear index is something i am implementing since it does make searching for an edge easier. Thankyou so much !!.

Comment: @aditya glad to hear the answer was helpful.  The linear index concept with a border is actually something i've seen in some chess engines, as it's a data structure that greatly simplifies calculation of movement...  And yeah, if you're using SVGs, then presumably when you capture mouse events, you'll have the hexagon linear index value associated with the SVG that was clicked.  For posterity's sake and others stumbling into this Q&A, i plan to add a method that takes xy coordinates and determines the hexagon index.  This won't be needed by you, but maybe others in the future...

Comment: FWIW adjusted the code snippet to include method `hexagonIndex` which translates (x,y) canvas coordinates to the corresponding hexagon linear index.

Comment: we just finished with the website, the algorithms have not been perfected yet but in case anyone is interested visited: https://aarnavv.github.io/Vagus/

Comment: @aditya looking good.  nice clean interface with a pleasant soft touch to actions in the hexagon grid...